# Ethics around applying for a job with a consultancy, I'm in the process of commissioning work with

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom

I've known a particular consultancy for two years, I briefly got them to do some work for the business I work for, but they were gazumped by another for the work. I've recently been told by my CIO to go ahead and reach out to the my recommended consultancy to help us out.

We are only at early stages - first contact all over again, basically me describing our issues to them and asking for a Statement of Work and plan around what they can do for us.

Now, after that long initial chat with the consultancy, I then looked them up on LinkedIn, to discover they are recruiting, according to my profile and their requirements I'm a 100% match.

The company culture, work ethic and everything ticks my boxes as I'm very disenchanted with my current employer and am already on the job market.

Is there any issues regarding me applying for the job?

Comment: Don't forget the issue that the consultancy might reject you right now, because they don't want to get a contract cancelled because your current employer might not like this move.

Comment: If you're currently a minister of the Crown, you should take a careful look at section 7.25 and annex B of the Ministerial Code.  Some other workplaces may have equivalent codes of practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no conflict there as far as I can see.  You might want to take a look at the non-competition clause of your employment agreement to make sure though.

If the consultancy is providing your company with a service, it's not likely to be interpreted as a competitor, so you should be ok.

But check your agreement.